# Scraping PHP from popup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Is there a way to scrape data from a popup? I'd like to import data from the site tennisinsight.com.

For example, http://tennisinsight.com/match-preview/?matchid=191551201 
This is a sample data extraction link. When clicking "overview" there is a button with "Match Stats", I'd like to be able to import those data from many links in a text or CSV file.

What's the best way to accomplish this? Is Scrapy able to do this? Is there software able to do this?

Comment: Aside from Ryan's answer, you can also use a headless browser that supports JavaScript, e.g. PhantomJS. You'll probably want to find a Python driver for it though (search on GitHub). Ryan's approach will be faster though, but the PhantomJS approach may be more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You want to open the network analyzer in your browser (e.g. in Web Developer in Firefox) to see what requests are sent when you click the "match stats" button in order to replicate them using python.

When I do it, a POST request is sent to http://tennisinsight.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php with `action` and `matchID` parameters.

You presumably already know the match ID (see URL you posted above), so you just need to set up a POST request for each matchID you have.

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://tennisinsight.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data={'action':'showMatchStats', 'matchID':'191551201'})
print r.text #this is your content of interest
```